# Send more than one post request

Tags: c#, post, httpwebrequest

I want to send multiply post requests to a website.
I've search over Google and got to this code:

```
 class Program
{
    public static HttpWebRequest HttpWReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://example.com/login.php");
    public static ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
    public static string postData = "";
    public static bool first = true;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string uname = "", pass = "", Final = "";

        while (1>0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter uname ,then password");
            uname = Console.ReadLine();
            pass = Console.ReadLine();
            if (uname == "0")
                break;
            Final = letstry(uname, pass);

            Console.WriteLine(Final);
            Console.WriteLine("Finish That");
        }
    }

    public static string letstry(string uname, string pass)
    {  
        postData = "uname=" + uname;
        postData += ("&pass=" + pass);
        byte[] data = encoding.GetBytes(postData);
        if (first)
        {
            HttpWReq.Method = "POST";
            HttpWReq.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            HttpWReq.ContentLength = data.Length;
            first = !first;
        }

        Stream newStream = HttpWReq.GetRequestStream();
        newStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        newStream.Close();

        WebResponse resp = HttpWReq.GetResponse();
        StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream());
        return sr.ReadToEnd().Trim();
    }
}
```

I'm getting an error that the connection was closed (newstream).
Why can't I use the same connection to send more than one request?

The only idea that I can think about it's to send a stream var to `letstry`, instead of creating `newstream`.

I'm no expert, so I'm sorry for any unnecessary mistakes.

tyvm for your help:)

Comment: Why do you write `while (1>0)`? `while (true)` is much clearer.

Comment: @Tim, yeah, I think so. I had to pause on that line and think what it actually meant.

Answer (score 3):

`WebRequest` is designed to do what it says: make one request. If you want to make multiple requests, just create new `WebRequest` each time.

If the `KeepAlive` property is `true`, the requests try to use the same connection, if possible. See [Understanding System.Net Connection Management and ServicepointManager](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adarshk/archive/2005/01/02/345411.aspx) for more information.